# SimpleXML_Load_String on XML with nested image tags not capturing the "url" attribute

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am attempting to parse xml using simplexml_load_string on an old server running PHP 5.3. One of the tags in the xml is  and has several nested  children with a url attribute. If I var_dump the SimpleXMLElement, images is just an array of strings (the text node children of each  tag) with no sign of the url attribute.

Any thoughts on why the url attribute on the  tags is not being captured?

I've tried shortening the url attributes on the image tags to about 15 characters and they're still not captured.

I've tried accessing the attributes as an array element of the image element as well as by calling the attributes() method on the image element.

Sample XML

```
<properties xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <property>
        <reference>####</reference>
        ...
        <images>
            <image url="https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_JUxtL~PunupG3r34QY7hcc7wMtgouw9c1H6DUbVNANjxM_Zg--.jpg">A2970_10776141.jpg</image>
            <image url="https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_AwVzHs_Ajc3bPh6tAooCEbZkq_ZYbRT5eAjUXsq3Znh_f~Vw--.jpg">A2970_10776142.jpg</image>
        ...
        <links/>
    </property>
    <property>
    ...
    </property>
</properties>
```

My Code

```
$feed = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$properties = simplexml_load_string($feed);
foreach ($properties as $property) {
  var_dump($property->images);
  exit;
}
```

Result

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(19) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "A2970_10776141.jpg"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "A2970_10776142.jpg"
    ...
  }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
foreach ($property->images as $image)
{
    var_dump($image['url']);
    var_dump($image->attributes());
}
```

$image['url'] outputs NULL

$image->attributes() outputs error about calling attributes() on a non-object

Ideally, var_dumping $property->images would yield:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(19) {
    [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
          array(1) {
            ["url"]=>
              string(162) "https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_JUxtL~PunupG3r34QY7hcc7wMtgouw9c1H6DUbVNANjxM_Zg--.jpg"
          }
        }
        [text]=> "A2970_10776141.jpg"
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot how much I hated SimpleXML. This worked for me:

```
<?php

$feed = file_get_contents('test.xml');
$properties = simplexml_load_string($feed);
foreach ($properties as $property)
{
   foreach($property->images[0] as $image)
   {
      print($image['url'] . "\n");                                                 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the correct value for your foreach loop, you should actually be using `$property->images->image` as it is those elements you want to iterate over. After that you can take your pick of methods to access the `url` attribute:

```
$properties = simplexml_load_string($feed);
foreach ($properties as $property) {
    foreach ($property->images->image as $image) {
        echo $image['url'] . PHP_EOL;
        echo $image->attributes()['url'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_JUxtL~PunupG3r34QY7hcc7wMtgouw9c1H6DUbVNANjxM_Zg--.jpg 
https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_JUxtL~PunupG3r34QY7hcc7wMtgouw9c1H6DUbVNANjxM_Zg--.jpg 
https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_AwVzHs_Ajc3bPh6tAooCEbZkq_ZYbRT5eAjUXsq3Znh_f~Vw--.jpg 
https://#####.#########.###/imgV1/QGcM5YXB7ITu20usXVas9zwwpfszaQl0S7VJWTlCweLw8h1OJgGrQ8SrQZiKyUwAW5EgBoJga_AwVzHs_Ajc3bPh6tAooCEbZkq_ZYbRT5eAjUXsq3Znh_f~Vw--.jpg
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/j9Rt6)

Answer (score 0):

Nested xml attributes are little bit problematic while using php simplexml
child attributes not capturing by simplexml.

But, you can simply use this function. this will recursively get all xml attributes.

```
function parseXMLtoArray($xml){
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$result = [];

function parse($xml, &$res){
    $res['name'] = $xml->getName();
    $res['value'] = $xml->__toString();
    foreach ($xml->attributes() as $k => $v){
        $res['attr'][$k] = $v->__toString();
    }

    foreach($xml->children() as $child){
        parse($child, $res['children'][]);
    }
}

parse($x, $result);

return $result;

}

$resArray = parseXMLtoArray($rawXml);

print_r($resArray);
```